# Select2.min.js dropdown is not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

[IN this image select2 js (multi select is not working..)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBI3P.png)

hello Everyone,

Problem:- I have use select2.min.js for multiple selection in drop down, its perfectly working in mozilla firefox  but its does't working in chrome.
please provide me solution ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    <select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
            <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
            <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
            <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
            <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
            <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
        </select>

$("#e1").select2();
```

working both chrome  and mozilla

Example http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/62/

Comment: hello pawan , my code exact like you but , still not working on chrome.